# matplotlib, pandas, how to generate a histogram of timedeltas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas.DataFrame `df` with that contains the following series:

```
Time
2182447     0 days 05:44:00
2182447     0 days 05:49:00
3129563     0 days 22:09:00
13341029    0 days 16:49:00
13341029    0 days 16:58:00
25622668    0 days 08:24:00
25622668    0 days 08:28:00
30077018   24 days 15:01:00
30077018   24 days 15:09:00
20131954    0 days 06:18:00
```

I would like to plot a histogram of the timedeltas. However:

```
hist(df)
df.Time.hist()
# both functions give the same error
>>> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc less input from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
hist(df.Time.astype('timedelta64[h]'))
```

You can use different units in the astype argument. Here I use ´h´ hours.

[More detailed description can be found here.](https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/05/16/pandas-timedelta-histograms-unit-conversion-and-overflow-danger/)